# Retornar booleano al guardar en la base de datos Mongoose, TypeScript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una función de creación de usuarios. La misma recibe unos datos por parámetros crea un modelo de usuario y ejecuta el método para guardar el documento en `MongoDB`. La función debería de devolver un true en caso de haberse podido hacer la inserción o un false en caso de error.
Como hago una petición a la base de datos mi función la hago con `async | await`

```js
    async createUser(name: String, email: String, pass: String, admin?: Boolean | false): Promise<Boolean> {
        const newUser: User = new UserModel({
            Name: name,
            Email: email,
            Password: pass,
            Admin: admin
        });
        return await newUser.save()
                        .then( () => new Promise<Boolean>((resolve, reject)=>resolve(true) ))
                        .catch(() => new Promise<Boolean>((resolve, reject)=>resolve(false) ));
    }
```

Esto me da el siguiente error

> The return type of an async function or method must be the global
>   Promise type.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberías extraer el then y el catch de esta función para que tenga sentido el uso del await. En primer lugar la promesa que devuelves es de tipo Boolean y tendría más sentido que fuera de tipo User para así hacer lo siguiente.

```
async createUser(name: String, email: String, pass: String, admin?: Boolean | undefined): Promise<User> {
        const newUser: User = new UserModel({
            Name: name,
            Email: email,
            Password: pass,
            Admin: admin
        });
        return await newUser.save();
}
```

Una vez tienes esta función cuando la llames para guardar un usuario yo actuaría de la siguiente forma

```
const newUser = createUser('Joaquin', 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 'password', true ).then(data => {
            console.log(data); // Ver si ha ido bien
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error); // Ver si ha ido mal
        });
```

No es la única manera ni la mejor, pero creo que solucionaría tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

El Error es porque no estas retornando una Promesa y el await lo espera  , la solución para esto es crear una promesa

```
async createUser(name: String, email: String, pass: String, admin?: Boolean | undefined): Promise<Boolean> {
    const newUser: User = new UserModel({
        Name: name,
        Email: email,
        Password: pass,
        Admin: admin
        });
       return await newUser.save()
                           .then(() => new Promise((resolver, rechazar)=>resolver(true))
                           .catch(() =>  new Promise((resolver, rechazar)=>resolver(false))
}
```

Comment: Al implementar ese código me indica el error: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: lo siento olvide unos parentesis, intenta de nuevo

Comment: Actualice el post. Ese es mi código en este momento. El error persiste

Comment: El error era mio no me había dado cuenta de que se había auto importado la libreria q.